# Laravel Search Between $from and $to date not working

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

Controller:

```php
if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
    $from = $request->input('from');
    $to = $request->input('to');
    if ($request->has('search'))
    {
        // select search
        $searchReports = DB::table('hr_leave_requests AS lr')
            ->join('hr_leave_types AS lt', 'lr.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
            ->join('hr_employees AS em', 'lr.employee_id', '=', 'em.id')
            ->where('lr.leave_status', 4)
            ->where('lr.company_id', $userCompany)
            ->whereBetween('lr.commencement_date', [$from, $to])
            ->select('em.employee_code', DB::raw("CONCAT(em.first_name,' ',em.last_name) as full_name"), 'lr.commencement_date', 'lr.resumption_date', 'lr.no_of_days', 'lt.leave_type_name')
            ->get();

        return view('report.leave_reports.hr_leave_taken_by_date_report', ['searchReports' => $searchReports]);
    }
```

This is the view blade:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  // $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.fromDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      duration: 'fast',
      yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<form action="{{route('reports.leaveReport')}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="from" class="col-form-label">From:</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="from" class="form-control fromDate">
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="from" class="col-form-label">To:</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="to" class="form-control fromDate">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('reports/leaveReport', 'LeaveReportsController@leaveReport')->name('reports.leaveReport');
Route::post('reports/leaveReport', 'LeaveReportsController@leaveReport')->name('reports.leave');
```

I am using `JQuery UI datepicker` amd `commencement_date` for `$from` and `$to`. As I select `$from` and `$to` and submit, I expect it to filter according to the selected date, but nothing is displayed.

If I remove the `$from` and `$to` and load it directly on the view blade, it works fine.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do the following, before you do `return view(....)`, remove the `get()` from `$searchReports ` and do `dd($searchReports->toSql());` and see the response (it will be an SQL query), so copy that query and go to your favorite MySQL manager and run the query, see the actual response, and see if the `$from` and `$to` values are correct in the query. If they are correct, then see if the query replies correctly (I am assuming it will not) so try playing with the values and that way you can debug the problem. You can also share the query you get and the values of both `$from` and `$to` in your questi

Comment: You first check static value in `whereBetween` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('from'));

and it works.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same date format between your input and your database. Date format must be similar to the defined format in your database table otherwise you need to convert.

You can change your datepicker format like this:

```
$('.fromDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    // ..
}
```

or alternatively, you can convert the date format on your controller using the Carbon library.

```
$from = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('from'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I got this error:  
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\vendor\esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Traits\\Creator.php(645): Carbon\\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01-03-2021', NULL)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Report\\LeaveReportsController.php(139): Carbon\\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01-03-2021').           This is how it appears in the database.